# I required to know that whether we have any property to find element using innertext? As all the other parameters available are in autogenerated ones

Tags: c#, selenium

I have tried using CSS Selector and Xpath i.e Absolute Xpath .Cannot take relative Xpath since the ID's are autogenerated ones.I am focussing on IE11 browser.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you're trying to achieve and what've you've already tried (providing sample code is that's not working is usually very helpful)

Comment: Following is my html code... Autogenerated ID can be seen .
Some tags dont have text, cannot use innertext in some areas                             

<div id="ext-gen495" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" style="width: 166px;">
<input id="ext-gen497" type="hidden" name="ocontact" value=""/>
<input id="ext-comp-1162" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-trigger-noedit x-form-focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" size="24" readonly=""/>
<img id="ext-gen496" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" alt="" src="/home/shared/s.gif"/>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find the element using XPath contains method

Example:-

```
//a[contains(.,'Your Text')]
```

Replace `Your Text` with your Text

Refer :-

http://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have tried using //input[starts-with(@class, 'search-')] but i get 20 matches. how to select the specific one which i want?

Comment: use an array count like if your element is on 2nd place then use //input[starts-with(@class, 'search-')][2]

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried with that,but its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right then you are trying to find an element which has some text and all other attributes are dynamic. You should use `//*[text()='yourText']`

Comment: Some tags like input tags dont have text in it.Values are fetched for some input tag dropdown list.
Below is the html code mentioned

'<div id="ext-gen495" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" style="width: 166px;">
<input id="ext-gen497" type="hidden" name="ocontact" value=""/>
<input id="ext-comp-1162" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-trigger-noedit x-form-focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" size="24" readonly=""/>
<img id="ext-gen496" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" alt="" src="/home/shared/s.gif"/>
</div>'

Comment: I have tried using //input[starts-with(@class, 'search-')]
but i get 20 matches. how to select the specific one which i want?

Comment: In that case you shall find an element on the page which has any fix and unique attribute in it and then using that element you can navigate to the desired web element by xpath functions like parent, following-sibling or preceding-sibling. You watch this video that'll help you URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67bzMdbhIuw